# Bootstrap datepicker in bootstrap button drop down

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, event-handling, datepicker

**My requirement** : I am working on a twitter bootstrap button dropdown (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) and using bootstrap-datepicker (http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/#examples) in one of the list items as shown in below image.

[image]

As per my requirement, I need to have month calendar in last item and clicking on that opens the bootstrap-datepicker and I should be able to select month & year.

**Problem I am facing** : When I open that datepicker and select any month or year or click on any of the navigation in datepicker to move to another month or year, the  button drop down hides, but the datepicker remains there as in the below image. I have been trying but not able to get it working.

[image]

**What I think** (not sure its correct or not) : When I click on datepicker, it is being attached to the body element directly where as all the list items and thier children are deep down in html. So, even if i try to stop event propagation for any click inside dropdown, it wont count for datepicker, as it is appended to body. ( Just for more info I have some actions defined on click of other list items)

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this, I really need to get this thing working for my project.

Comment: You need to add some code as well and possible a fiddle to demonstate your issue to get more responses. But anyways is this what you are trying? http://jsfiddle.net/hTKYR/

Comment: @PSL - You are right and sorry about that, heres the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n3NNx/ . Strangely, here it seems to be working fine, the drop down doesnt hide when i select the month, but when this whole code is used in the page along with other things, the drop down hides, as I shown in the 2nd image in my post.               (I kind of used resources in the fiddle from yours, didnt knew, as am creating it for first time)

Comment: So problem could be else where. Also just see the version of BS and other things in the fiddle and in your page.

Comment: @PSL - thats right, am just looking at that only. But thanks, I think u helped me to know that the problem is not this code. Something else is affecting this.

Comment: @PSL - I realized that the fiddle you shared had the datepicker from eyecon site (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) but I was originally using the one from eternicode (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js) which is just the improved & better version (previous one is a little buggy). And when i use this, i see the problem, here is the fiddle for that - http://jsfiddle.net/eqwWJ/ . Would u have any idea what's causing this, the difference in both the js files looks the culprit.

Comment: Figured out a solution see if that is feasible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With this date-picker you need to prevent propagation on the individual buttons. Add this in your script.

```
    $(document).on('click', 'span.month, th.next, th.prev, th.switch, span.year', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dT6AU/)**

Comment: thanks a lot, as in demo, it seems to be perfect. I will get that in my code & check when I get back to my desk on Monday morning.

Comment: I included that in my code and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for helping me out. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but I found another work-around.

#### Work-around

```
$('#your-datepicker')
    .datepicker()
    .on('show', function(e) {
        var $popup = $('.datepicker');
        $popup.click(function () { return false; });
    });
```

#### Explanation

The date-picker seems to add its HTML to the end of the `<body>` each time it's shown. The HTML for the pop-up looks something like the following:

```
<div
    class="
        datepicker
        datepicker-dropdown
        dropdown-menu
        datepicker-orient-left
        datepicker-orient-top
    "
    style="display: block; top: 202px; left: 712.5px; z-index: 1010;">
    <!-- More HTML here -->
</div>
```

Other solutions have suggested that preventing propagation of the `click` event can resolve the problem. One way to implement this is to handle the event and return `false`. Since the HTML is generated each time the pop-up is displayed, the interception may also need to be configured each time.

Comment: This one is just perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me either, and neither did @Sam's, although it did point me toward another solution that worked (thanks Sam). My problem was the datepicker was within another collapsible element that shouldn't collapse when dates are selected, etc. Here's my solution:

```
    $('#myDatepicker').datepicker().on('click', function () {
        $('.datepicker').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // prevent clicks on datepicker from collapsing 'parent'
        });
    });
```